# rewrite www. to non www without specifying the domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I was using this code to remove www from my domain:

```
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My problem is that I usually use subdomains and it doesn't work for them. (www.sub.example.com).

How do I rewrite to remove www whatever the domain is and even if it has subdomains?

Comment: What is your question?
Just Now - I upvoted it.

Comment: Sorry I submitted it accidentally just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#********** Remove www from address **********
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

This is a bit more correct than the other solution.

Edit:
I removed [L] as it isn't applicable here.
Though in most cases [NC] non-case sensitive is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use capture groups and combine with rewrites...  (Completely untested guess)

```
# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Looks like someone else beat me to it with that answer.  Not really gonna steal their thunder, if that's the right answer.